# python gio waiting for async operations to be done

Tags: python, file-io, pygtk, asynchronous

I have to mount a WebDav location and wait for the operation to be finished before to proceed (it's a script).
So I'm using the library in this way:

```
location = gio.File("dav://server.bb")
location.mount_enclosing_volume(*args,**kw) # The setup is not much relevant
location.get_path() # Returns None because it's not yet mounted since the call is async
```

How to wait until the device is mounted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait for termination, you need to call [mount_enclosing_volume_finished](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/class-giofile.html#method-giofile--mount-enclosing-volume-finish) with the async-result object returned by `mount_enclosing_volume` (alternatively, you could pass the latter a callback, if you want to operate asynchronously, but it looks like you want sync-like operations here).